# Hyperplane avoiding some finite set

Tags: linear-algebra

If R is a K-algebra, where K is an infinite field, does there exist a hyperplane not containing a certain finite set of points?
 I would appreciate in advance any person answering this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Pick any hyperplane through the origin (i.e. a subspace of codimension 1), say $W$. Then $R/W$ (as a vector space) is isomorphic with $K$. So it has infinitely many cosets. Each point in your finite set belongs to exactly one of these cosets. Thus there is a coset (in fact infinitely many) to which none of your points belong. This is your desired hyperplane.

Comment: When dim(R/W)=1, is it not true that R/W has only one coset?

Comment: We have 1 **dimension** worth of cosets - which is an infinite set as long as our field is.